# Vue.JS @click active style deactive after @click on different component

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and I'm trying to achieve this navigation like behavior in code. What I have here is a simple list of servers and I want to have a different background color for "selected server" so it would be visible what was selected. My problem is that the way I coded it is that the active attribute stays after I selected a different server. What I would like it to do is once I select different server it will take away the active class from the one that was selected before.

```
<template>
  <li
    class="list-group-item"
    style="cursor: pointer"
    @click="serverSelected"
    v-bind:style='{"background-color": (isActive? "yellow" : "orange" )}'>
    Server #{{ server.id }} Server status: #{{ server.status }}
  </li>
</template>

<script>
    import { serverBus } from "../../main";

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return{
                isActive: false
            }
        },
        props: ['server'],
        methods: {
            serverSelected() {
                serverBus.$emit('serverSelected', this.server);
                this.isActive = !this.isActive;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This would be easier to reason about if the parent component (or something else) owned the state. In other words, I'd recommend passing `isActive` as a prop. Then you just need to emit a `click` event.

Comment: My guess is iterate over the list of servers first and remove the active class.

Answer (score 0):

Shared states should be store in parent component, in this case, only parent component should know what server was selected.

You can change style/class directly from parent, or you can pass a prop like `isSelected` to each child component, example parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <server
      v-for="(server) in servers"
      :key="server.id"
      :is-selected="server.id == activeServer"
      :server="server"
      @selected="selectServer(server.id)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      servers: [
        {
          id: 1,
          status: 'ok'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          status: 'ok'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          status: 'ng'
        },
      ],
      activeServer: null,
    }
  }
  methods: {
    selectServer(serverId) {
      this.activeServer = serverId
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And child component:

```
<template>
  <li
    class="list-group-item"
    style="cursor: pointer"
    @click="serverSelected"
    v-bind:style='{"background-color": isSelected}'>
    Server #{{ server.id }} Server status: #{{ server.status }}
  </li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['server', 'isSelected'],
  methods: {
    serverSelected() {
      this.$emit('selected', this.server.id)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```